# Binding single datagrid with list and individual data item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and was trying to bind data to datagrid. I have a list of items which is binded to Datagrid. The same datagrid also has few columns (2 columns) whose values are not obtained from the list but are individual values which needs to be binded to those two datagrid columns. Can anyone help me find the solution please?
Below is the xaml code.

ItemList is the list of items binded to the DataGrid. It has "PropertyName" and "PropertyValue" which is binded to datagrid columns.

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="dtgridUpload"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" IsReadOnly="True">
                  <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <TextBlock Text="Name" />                                         
                        </StackPanel>
                 </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="200" Binding="{Binding PropertyValue}"   IsReadOnly="True"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit"  Binding="{Binding PropertyUnit}" IsReadOnly="True"/>                               
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1" Width="200"  IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}" Binding="{Binding PropertyName1}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit1"  Binding="{Binding PropertyUnit1}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

.cs code

```
  private List<DeviceData_VM> itemList;
    public List<DeviceData_VM> ItemList
    {
        get { return itemList; }
        set
        {
            itemList= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemList");
        }
    }
     TextReader readStream = new StreamReader("output.xml");
     ItemList= (List<DeviceData_VM>)serialiser.Deserialize(readStream);
```

But "PropertyName1" and "PropertyValue1" is obtained from other variable.

```
   void GetFileData()
        {
           string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\WriteLines.txt");
                List<DeviceData_VM>  tempeDataLst = new List<DeviceData_VM>();
                for (var i = 0; i < readText.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (readText[i][0] == ';' || readText[i][0] == '/' || readText[i][0] == '@' || readText[i][0] == '#' || readText[i][0] != 'A')
                        continue;
                    var cols = readText[i].Split('\t');
                    DeviceData_VM fileData = new DeviceData_VM();
                    fileData.PmName = cols[1];
                    fileData.PmValue = cols[2];                      
                    fileData.PmUnit = cols[4];
                    tempeDataLst.Add(fileData);
                   TabInfo tabCompInfo = new TabInfo();
                   foreach (var tabItem in LstTabInfo)
                    {
                        foreach (var devItem in tabItem.LstPmData1)
                        {
                            if(devItem.PmName == fileData.PmName)
                            {
                                if(fileData != null){

                                    tabCompInfo.RightData = fileData;                                       
                                    break;
                                }                                 
                            } 
                        } 
                   }
               }
           }
```

So i have ProperName1 and PropertyValue1 in "RightData". How to bind these to the datagrid columns? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a type which will combine all columns in same item

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding to your DeviceData_VM Model the extra properties you wish to bind?

After that, add your values to each DeviceData_VM from what ever data source you wish.

Add each item to your ItemList and your binding should work as expected.